# How myCompare function is working in vector pair sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

How does the myCompare function works in vector pair sorting? like what is p1 and what is p2? I want to know what is happening in the function (like in debugging).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

bool myCompare(pair<int, int> p1, pair<int, int> p2){
    return p1.first<p2.first;
}

int main(){
    int arr[]={10,16,7,14,5,3,12,9};
 
    vector <pair <int, int>> v;

    for(int i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++){
        v.push_back(make_pair(arr[i],i));
    }
    for(auto a:v){
        cout<<a.first<<" "<<a.second<<"    ";
    }cout<<endl;

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),myCompare);

    for(auto a:v){
        cout<<a.first<<" "<<a.second<<"    ";
    }cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You have the types explicitly declared. And for any sorting function you need some way to compare two elements to know which order the sorting should be in, which is exactly what your `myCompare` does

Comment: You wrote the function and are sending it as the custom-comparator to `std::sort`, but don't know how/why it works? Um...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that:

1. `myCompare` tells the `std::sort` function **how** to sort integer pairs.
2. `p1` and `p2` are the integer pairs to be compared.

Think about it. If you have 2 pairs of integers, say {10, 4} and {20, 2}, how would you know how to sort them?

- Should {10, 4} come first because 10 < 20?
- Should {20, 2} come first because 2 < 4?
- Maybe you want to use both values in your comparison, like (10/4) < (20/2)?

The `myCompare` function simply describes that the first comparison method should be used, only taking into account the first value of each pair.

So in this example where `p1` is {10, 4} and `p2` is {20, 2}, `myCompare` would order them `p1, p2` because 10 < 20.

In your `main()` function, `myCompare` will be called many times while `std::sort` sorts through your vector and passes in the 2 integer pairs (as `p1` and `p2`) it is comparing in that moment.

Answer (score 1):

A sort function typically does a series of comparisons to build a sorted range of given elements. For comparison you can use less than or greater than operator for ascending or descending ordering. You can also define and use a completely unique comparison operator for your interpretation of your data type as long as it satisfies `Compare` requirements.

A comparison function defines an ordering on a type. It takes two elements as input, and returns a boolean. A comparison function `comp` must satisfy some rules to define a meaningful ordering (and no UB) such as:

```
For all a, comp(a,a)==false
If comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false
if comp(a,b)==true and comp(b,c)==true then comp(a,c)==true
```

In your example, `v` is sorted using `myCompare` function defined as a comparison operator on type `pair<int, int>`. `myCompare` only takes the first element of the pair into account, which is perfectly valid and satisfies all the rules for [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).